# Marking default value in Selectbox while using two array in Angular

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-select

I build a control using an Object that I get it from external source.

```
var field= {
          "attributeName": "Country",
          "dbColumnName": "location",
          "fieldType": "DROP_DOWN",
          "optionName": ['US', 'AUS', 'UK', 'IND'],
          "optionValue": ['123','456','789','0123']
        }
```

Control is created from above object

```
<select name="{{field.attributeName}}" ng-model="formControlsValues[field.dbColumnName]"/>
   <option ng-repeat="item in field.optionName track by $index" ng-value="field.optionValue[$index]">
       {{item}}
   </option>
</select>
```

field.optionName is an Array and item will be a display value.
field.optionValue[$index] is another array mapped for values.

Marking default value in Selectbox while using above two arrays in Angular,
how can it be achieved ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please clarify it. Also you're closing the `<select>` tag in wrong place...

Comment: @developer033, Can you please have a look now. Have edited my question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it right, you want to set a default value in the select input. 
Sticking with your code, I set a `default_index` value and used it to init input and options.

```
<select name="{{field.attributeName}}" 
  ng-init="field.itemsel = field.optionValue[default_index]" 
  ng-model="field.itemsel">
   <option ng-repeat="item in field.optionName track by $index" 
   ng-selected="default_index == $index"
   ng-value="field.optionValue[$index]">
       {{item}}
   </option>
</select>
<p>
  OptionValue to be used for whatever: {{field.itemsel}} 
</p>
```

please check this [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/wscnbe67/) I created.

Additionally I would rewrite your code using `ng-options` (as suggested in [Angular select input documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ng/directive/select)):

```
<select name="{{field.attributeName}}" 
  ng-options="index as item for (index, item) in field.optionName" 
  ng-init="indexselected='1'"
  ng-model="indexselected">
</select>
<p>Selected index: {{indexselected}}</p>
<p>Option Value: {{field.optionValue[indexselected]}}</p>
```

check this other [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/fo9axbnc/) I created.
If your doubt was different, please point it out more clearly.

Comment: Bingo !! Thanks @mtb I made few changes in your code to suit my requirements. But your code in the key to lead me there.. :)

Comment: I made a small change like "ng-options='field.optionValue[index] as item..." and ng-init="formControlsValues[field.dbColumnName]=field.initialValue" and ng-model="formControlsValues[field.dbColumnName]" in the control which will collect the changed value in the control.